# Is the 1990 Flash part of the Arrowverse continuity?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

<sub>Spoilers for the season two finale of *The Flash* (2014)</sub>

In episode 2x13 of *The Flash* (2014) we were shown a glimpse of John Wesley Shipp as Flash from the 1990 show.

[image: blurry depiction of the 1990 Flash]

In the season 2 finale we learn that

> there is an Earth-3, in which John Wesley Shipp plays the Flash.
>
>  [image: Flash portrayed by the 1990s actor, seen in S.T.A.R. Labs' facility. His helmet lets other people see his face, and his suit is regular "Flash" red, with a lightning bolt on the chest]

Also the 1990 Flash versions of Dr. McGee and Trickster were played by the same actors of their 2014 "Earth-1" doppelgangers:

[image: Left: 1990 Dr McGee, brown-haired female wearing earrings. Right: 2014 Dr McGee, short-haired blonde woman wearing a necklace. She's older than her 1990 version]

[image: Left: 1990 Trickster, who dyed his hair with sevral colors, wearing an Arlequin-like suit. Right: 2014 Trickster, wearing a regular suit, with a pink flower-like thing on the buttonhole]

### Is the 1990 show part of Earth-3? What is the relationship (if any) between the 1990 show and the Arrowverse?

Comment: My instinct says so, but I'm not sure as in the 90's show, John played the role of Barry Allen but here he is Jay Garrick. So,... hmmm....

Comment: The 1990 show probably isn't part of Earth 3, because as you say in 1990 he played Barry Allen and JWS plays Jay Garrick.  However, the multiverse is infinite, so it's probably fair to imagine that the 1990 show is a part of the multiverse that Flash/Arrow/etc exist in.

Comment: Additional information in favor of the yes, in the 1990 show, there Is a Jay Allen who is Barry's brother. He apparently does not goes beyond the pilot. and ultimately add more confusion. He is NOT a twin brother, and is played by a different actor. But considering

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the 2018 Arrowverse crossover, this is confirmed as John Wesley Shipp plays Barry Allen/Flash from Earth-90 (90? get it?), reprising his original 1990s role and costume.  Picture is of him standing next to the bodyswapped Barry Allen as the Green Arrow.

[image: Flash in his 90s (kitsch-looking) red costme with the emblematic chest lightning bolt symbol. Next to him is Barry Allen of the 2014 TV show dressed as Green Arrow, complete with the hood, domino mask and quiver]

Answer (score 7):

No, not conclusively, because John Wesley Shipp's character is the wrong person.

In the 1990's *Flash* TV show, Shipp plays Barry Allen, but in the 2014 TV show, Shipp's Earth-3 character was Jay Garrick. Since Henry's mother's maiden name is Garrick, it's strongly implied that there's a close relationship between the two characters, but they are not the same.

Jay Garrick is identified explicitly in the show as *Henry* Allen's doppelganger, though it's never explained why Henry Allen's doppelganger would have his mother's maiden last name (maybe marriage customs are reversed on Earth-3?). So he can't be the same character as the one from 1990's *Flash*.

Comment: Barry's mother's maiden name is not Garrick. It's Henry's mother's maiden name, or, Barry's grandmother. Video/article [here](http://www.cinemablend.com/television/How-Flash-Just-Proved-Barry-Jay-Garrick-Connected-135707.html).

Comment: John Wesley Shipp played both Earth-3 Jay Garrick and Earth-90 Barry Allen in the CW series. This may not have been the case yet when you wrote this in 2016 however.